# Contour lines and implicit function theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, implicit-function-theorem

$f = y^2-x^2+x^3$
I want to find all points $(x_0,y_0)$ such for some neighbor set $f(x,y) = f(x_0,y_0)$ is set $x=\varphi(y), \varphi \in C^{\infty}, \varphi(y_0)=x_0$.

Comment: What's the problem? You know you need to use the implicit function theorem. Use it.

Comment: It's works for $f(x,y)= 0$($f_{x}'(x_0,y_0) \neq 0$), but i have $f(x,y)-f(x_0,y_0)=0$ and i don't know what to do.

Comment: It's not true that $f_x(x_0,y_0)\neq 0$ in general. You might be misthinking something which I can't pinpoint.

Comment: I mean for equation $f(x,y)=0$ exists $\varphi$(like $\varphi$ in my question) only for points $(x_0,y_0)$ which satisfy $\partial_xf(x_0,y_0) \neq 0$.
(My english is very terrible, sorry)

Comment: You need to find all $(x_0,y_0)$ such that $\partial _xf(x_0,y_0)\neq 0$. You seem to know this. Can you do it?

Comment: But we have equation $f(x,y)-f(x_0,y_0)=0$

Comment: I see, same thing but with different variables. You need to find all $(a,b)$ such that $\partial _xf(a,b)\neq 0$.

Comment: In this case 'bad' points: $(0,y),(\frac{2}{3},y)$, but for $f(x,y)-f(1,1)=0$ there is another 'bad' points;(

Comment: Why do you say there other bad points? See [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%5E2-x%5E2%2Bx%5E3%2B1%3D0). The graph suggests '$x$ always is a function of $y$' in the equation $f(x,y)-f(1,1)=0$.

Comment: Oh yes, im sorry